# Producing an area chart in D3 similar to Highcharts Basic Area

Tags: d3.js, highcharts

Hoping someone can help me with what I think could be a simple problem.

Using this as an example: [Stacked Area Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885211)

I'd like to be able to replicate this, but having each series flush to the bottom of the axis to show a better representation of each series.

Highcharts calls this a "Basic" Area chart, where each series are coloured differently with varying opacity.

I'm not going to ask "IF" this is possible in D3, I'm sure it is, but if someone can explain how this could be done, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when one creates an areas chart each area start where the previous area ended (that taking in consideration that one area "starts" from the bottom). But you want to make it starts not from the end of another area but from the x-axis, right?

Ok, a couple of tips for achieving this:

- To make it more "efficient" start adding the area at the chart bottom and the rest of areas, rather than using `d3.append`, use `d3.insert` which
  will let you insert new areas BEFORE the area you just added.
- To apply opacity for each area separately use `.each()`.
- Your code would look like this:

  ```
  d3.select('svg g')
  .selectAll('path.area')
  .data(areas)
  .enter()
  .insert('path','path.area:first-child')
  .attr('class','area')
  .attr('d', function(d,i) {
      return yourAreaFunction(d,i);
  })
  .each(function(d,i) {
      d3.select(this)
      .style('fill', yourFillFunction(d,i))
      .style('opacity', function() {
          return ((1 / areas.length) * (i + 1));
      })
  });
  ```

IMPORTANT NOTE: This code is just a scrap, I have not tried it myself. Nonetheless it works as an aproximation of what I think you're looking for.

UPDATE: I checked the formula used for the opacity and I came across with a better one. Actually, I think it's the right one IF using different colors per area,... if using same color then use `return (1 - (1 / areas.length) * i );`.

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you, does make perfect sense what you've said so will take that away and run with it.  Again, many thanks.